# (Stochastic) optimization with multivariate predictive distribution

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, optimization, bootstrap, stochastic-processes

Suppose I have a multivariate predictive distribution (dimension N). The distribution cannot be described in closed form with a mu vector and associated covariance matrix.

However, I can sample from the distribution various scenarios with associated probabilities. One can imagine sampling 100,000 scenarios to construct a matrix where each row represents the joint distribution for a scenario, and a probability is associated with each scenario.

Now let's say I have a weight vector and I am performing some optimization involving the distribution (for example, a mean-variance optimization) with some constraints.

Naturally, for any given draw from the distribution we can search for the optimal weights that maximize the mean-variance function: weights * sampled return - weights(transposed) * E * weights.

However, the optimal weights for one draw will in general not correspond to the optimal weights from another draw. Question - what is the optimal choice for the weight vector?

I believe the answer may involve a [stochastic optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_optimization) procedure, however, I am not familiar with this space and would like to validate this. There are also natural connections to the literature on robust optimization but the solutions here require closed form expressions for the multivariate distribution.

I have explored re-sampling which has an analogy to boot-strapping. This involves constructing optimal weights for many samples from the predictive distribution and somehow averaging or combining the weights. However, this approach is [flawed](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=796625&ei=-gFMTubyNsTOgAeoh4Rz&usg=AFQjCNG3zEY7-Ec0qK3jMjFBxvb7CtA-oQ) and lacks a theoretical basis.

How might I proceed to tackle this problem with stochastic optimization or some other technique?

Comment: when you say 'optimal weights' - optimal in what sense?

Comment: Optimal in the sense that the weight vector minimizes some objective function. For example consider the "minimize variance" objective function: Arg Min: weight vector(transposed) * covariance matrix * weight vector, where weight is the choice of the optimizer, and covariance matrix is estimated by repeated draws from the predictive distribution

Comment: So, are you using random number generation to build up a picture of the likelihood so that you can optimize some function of it's first two moments? Why not just generate a **ton** of data points, estimate the mean vector and covariance matrix (which you should be able to make arbitrarily close to the true mean and covariance by simply increasing $n$) and then do the optimization?

Comment: The issue with collapsing to the mean vector return is that the estimation risk (as represented by the predictive distribution) is assumed away. This is a robust optimization problem where you are looking for a weight vector that satisfies (as best as possible) competing possible realizations. A closed form solution to the problem assuming normally distributed distribution is here: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=681553 . To visualize the problem for N=2, essentially you are looking for weights that maximize utility defined by the ellipsoid on Figure 2 top of page 5